# Calculating size of Google Firestore documents

Tags: size, google-cloud-firestore, document, calculation

Firestore docs give details of how to manually calculate the stored size of a document, but there does not seem to be a function provided for this on any of document reference, snapshot, or metadata.

Before I attempt to use my own calculation, does anyone know of an official or unofficial function for this?

Here is my (completely untested) first cut for such a function from my interpretation of the docs at https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/storage-size

```
function calcFirestoreDocSize(collectionName, docId, docObject) {
    let docNameSize = encodedLength(collectionName) + 1 + 16
    let docIdType = typeof(docId)
    if(docIdType === 'string') {
        docNameSize += encodedLength(docId) + 1
    } else {
        docNameSize += 8
    }  
    let docSize = docNameSize + calcObjSize(docObject)

    return  docSize
}
function encodedLength(str) {
    var len = str.length;
    for (let i = str.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        var code = str.charCodeAt(i);
        if (code > 0x7f && code <= 0x7ff) {
            len++;
        } else if (code > 0x7ff && code <= 0xffff) {
            len += 2;
        } if (code >= 0xDC00 && code <= 0xDFFF) {
            i--;
        }
    }
    return len;
}

function calcObjSize(obj) {
    let key;
    let size = 0;
    let type = typeof obj;

    if(!obj) {
        return 1
    } else if(type === 'number') {
        return 8
    } else if(type === 'string') {
        return encodedLength(obj) + 1
    } else if(type === 'boolean') {
        return 1
    } else if (obj instanceof Date) {
        return 8
    } else if(obj instanceof Array) {
        for(let i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
            size += calcObjSize(obj[i])
        }
        return size
    } else if(type === 'object') {

        for(key of Object.keys(obj)) {
            size += encodedLength(key) + 1 
            size += calcObjSize(obj[key])
        }
        return size += 32
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this, or test your own implementation?

Comment: I tried out your implementation with Google's sample data (Task id:5730082031140864) from the docs you linked. Expected size is 131 bytes, your implementation gave 230 bytes. This is actually close enough for my purposes, I just wanted to make sure I wasn't approaching the limit. So thank you!

Comment: I just checked this against the current examples and it's almost perfect. It's only off because you don't need the +1 in the first line (document names only need the extra +16 unlike strings)... thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

In Android, if you want to check the size of a document against the maximum of 1 MiB (1,048,576 bytes), there is a library that can help you with that:

- https://github.com/alexmamo/FirestoreDocument-Android/tree/master/firestore-document

In this way, you'll be able to always stay below the limit. The algorithm behind this library is the one that is explained in the official documentation regarding the [Storage Size](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/storage-size).

Comment: This is awesome. Would be nice to have it directly in the FB SDK. I am trying to get grasp of how big my documents are (lot of nested data) so it's pretty hard to calculate manually.

Comment: @pagep Till they add that as a part of the SDK, this library does the trick.

Comment: Yep, but I have web only app. I might try to port the lib into JS - hopefully if I find a time. Chers

Comment: @pagep Hehe sounds good. Good luck with that ;)