# Get firestore collection size

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

**TL;DR** Is there an API to get firestore collection size instead of us having to do so manually?

So according to their [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/storage-size#document-size), one can calculate the document size by identifying their datatypes.

A sample code to illustrate the above is as follows:

```
import datetime

def calculate_doc_size(data):
    if isinstance(data, dict):
        size = 0
        for key, value in data.items():
            key_size = len(key) + 1
            value_size = calculate_doc_size(value)
            key_pair_size = key_size + value_size
            size += key_pair_size
        return size
    elif isinstance(data, str):
        return len(data) + 1
    elif any([isinstance(data, bool), data is None]):
        return 1
    elif isinstance(data, (datetime.datetime, float, int)):
        return 8
    elif isinstance(data, list):
        return sum([calculate_doc_size(item) for item in data])

def calculate_doc_name_size(path):
    size = 0
    for collection in path.split('/'):
        size += len(collection) + 1
    return size + 16

document = {'a': {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': None}, 'b': [1, 2, 3], 'c': [{'a': 1}]}
size =  calculate_doc_name_size('database/account1/my_doc_id') + calculate_doc_size(document) + 32
print(size) # prints 139
```

So my idea was to calculate the doc size in `on write` event using cloud functions and maintain a counter which specifies the collection size at any given point in time. (size being in bytes)

> By size I mean not the number of keys in the document but the storage taken.

Is there a better way to get the firestore collection / document size?

Use case:
Say I wanted to limit an account by storage space like how gmail does (15GB per user). I wanted to achieve that with each account being a collection identified by account_id.
Example:

```
- database
    - account 1
        - collection 1
        - collection 2
    - account 2
        - collection 1
        - collection 2
```

Related post: [calculating size of google firestore documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49473148/calculating-size-of-google-firestore-documents)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a better way to get the firestore collection / document size?

Nope, that's pretty much what I'd do. Well... in general I'd try to steer away from such operations as they are highly volatile. But if you really need to know how much space the documentation in a collection take up, aggregating the sum of each document's size is the way to go for calculating it, and Cloud Functions seem like a natural technology to perform that calculation on every update.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Will any such APIs be added to firestore? Not asking for roadmap as such. This can also be useful to find out if the document size is above the restricted limit of say 1MB. I am looking for something like `db.collection('some-collection').getSize()` or even better `db.collection('some-collection').document('some-doc-id').getSize()`

Comment: At this point no work is being done on adding such a "storage size of collection" to the API, nor do I personally see a lot of demand for this specific functionality. You can always cast your vote by [filing a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/).

Comment: Sure will add it as a feature request. But pretty sure the firebase team is busy developing the `OR queries` support in firestore for now which has received quite a lot of traction, so this will be sidelined. This feature will be useful to find the data distribution across all collections and subcollections and for debugging. Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use firestore_size to calculate the size of the document in firestore.

install using:

```
pip install firestore_size
```

Following is an example of how it can be used:

```
from firestore_size.calculate import document_size

# initialize firebase and firestore client

collection = db.collection("data")
doc = collection.doc(id).get()
data = doc.to_dict()

doc_size = document_size(data)
print("Doc Size is ", doc_size)
```

Checkout more here: https://github.com/WaseemSabir/firestore_size